# JavaScript logs objects without executing newlines on \n

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
class MyObject{
  constructor(prop_a, prop_b, prop_c) {
    this.property_a = property_a;
    this.property_b = property_b;
    this.property_c = property_c;
  }

const myObject = new MyObject(...data);
```

and it looks like this in the log output:

```
myObject {
    property_a:0001,
    property_b:somestringsandlettersthat\n havenewlines\n andmorenwelines\n andmorenwelines,
    property_c:someotherstuff
}
```

but i want it like this:

```
myObject {
    property_a:0001,
    property_b:somestringsandlettersthat 
havenewlines
andmorenwelines,
andmorenwelines
    property_c:someotherstuff
}
```

The newlines should also be done on the \n not only on new properties.

The logger i use is: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-logger

In the console.log(myObject) it looks even worse:

```
myObject {
    property_a:0001, property_b:somestringsandlettersthat\n havenewlines\n andmorenwelines\n andmorenwelines, property_c:someotherstuff
}
```

Someone has an idea?

Comment: How are you constructing `myObject`?

Comment: This is an object. This is normal to see it like this in the console. Where do you want to output it ?

Comment: @Weedoze I want to log it in the console as well as in a file.

Comment: Why would you format it like this in the console ? The best thing I am thinking of is to format the object into a string

Comment: @CodingIntrigue see update

Comment: @Weedoze because of readability

Comment: @Gobliins `property_b` must have those newlines escaped. Try `this.property_b = property_b.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");`? Or change `property_b` at source to contain `\n` rather than `\\n`

Comment: i tried both solutions but the output unfortunately looks unchanged.  I think that the console.log and the logger itself seem to escape the new lines on their own.